# What are the meanings of the words 「えぐりこむ」and「べし」?

Tags: translation, words, manga

Here is the sentence I have seen them from a boxing Manga.

ひじを左{ひだり}わきからはなさない心{こころ}がまえで.....
やや内{ない}角{かく}をねらい

**えぐりこむ**ようにして...打{う}つ**べし**！

Especially 「べし」, I don't know the purpose to use it in the context.

**Another question:** As my understanding to the content, am I correctly translating?

Translation: From the left armpit, keep the elbow close to the front of the chest and aim to the inside corner (of the opponent) then move forward (to him) to punch/hit.

Comment: えぐりこむ sounds somewhat weird to me. It's just like saying "gouge in" if put literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

えぐり is the 連用形 (continuative form) of えぐる, which means "to hollow out", "to gouge"

えぐり + 込む is a 複合動詞 (compound verb). The second verb (後項動詞) in a compound usually loses its original meaning. A small list of such verbs can be found in [this](http://www.fluentu.com/japanese/blog/essential-common-japanese-verbs-list/) fluentu article.

込む alone can be translated as "to be crowded", whereas this meaning is lost here and it's more something like "to do something completely", "to do something extremely". A great website for understanding those verbs is http://vvlexicon.ninjal.ac.jp/db/, where you can click on "Search by V2" and search for 込む. There you will get plenty of different examples with verb compounds using 込む, covering all the different nuances that 込む might have.

べし is the same as べき, which means "to be supposed to do", "to should do something" in this case.

～ようにして打つべし becomes "you are supposed to hit as if you were hollowing out something completely"

Comment: I think to be precise we should probably distinguish [助動詞](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E_%28%E5%9B%BD%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95%29) (e.g. 行き**ます** or 行か**ない** or 打つ**べし**) from [補助動詞](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A3%9C%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E) (e.g. ～て**しまう** or ～て**いる**) from [V2 verbs that form 複合動詞](http://vvlexicon.ninjal.ac.jp/) (e.g. 飲み**込む** or 食べ**終わる**).  Unfortunately I don't know a short way to say that last one―in English or in Japanese!

Comment: According to wikipedia, it is called 後項動詞. Similarily, you can call the first part 前項動詞 or 連用形.

Comment: I think the nuance of 込む in えぐり込む is more like "inward/inside", which is found in 差し込む, 押し込む, 飛び込む, 詰め込む etc. Whereas 込む as "completely" is found in 作り込む, 寝込む, やりこむ, etc. Some verbs (e.g., 読み込む, 走り込む) are used in both ways.